# Button is not working correctly (android studio)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-button

I'm a little newbie on android, and my button it's not working properly when i run my app.
Here is my java code:

```
package com.example.neak.phore;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient;
import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler;
import com.loopj.android.http.RequestParams;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.Header;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    Button btLoginL;
    EditText etEmail, etPassL;
    TextView tvRegistrarGo;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btLoginL = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btLoginL);
        etEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etEmailL);
        etPassL = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassL);
        tvRegistrarGo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvRegistrarGo);
        final String email = etEmail.getText().toString();
        final String pass = etPassL.getText().toString();

        btLoginL.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                EnviarDatos(email, pass);
            }


        });
        tvRegistrarGo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent registrar = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Registrar.class);
                startActivity(registrar);
            }
        });
    }

    public void EnviarDatos(String email, String pass){
        String URL = "192.168.2.15/android/login.php";
        RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
        params.put("email",email);
        params.put("pass", pass);
        AsyncHttpClient clienteL = new AsyncHttpClient();
        clienteL.put(URL, params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int i, Header[] headers, byte[] bytes) {
                getDataJson(new String(bytes));
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int i, Header[] headers, byte[] bytes, Throwable throwable) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Fallo en la conexion", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            }
        });
    }
    public ArrayList<String> getDataJson(String response){
        ArrayList<String> Logstat = new ArrayList<>();
        try{
            JSONArray recoger = new JSONArray(response);
            String status;
            status=recoger.getJSONObject(0).getString("estado");
            comprobar(status);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return Logstat;
    }
    public void comprobar(String status){
        if(status.equals("0")){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Usuario o contraseña incorrectos",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Login correcto",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="#25ae90"
    tools:context="com.example.neak.phore.MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Nombre de usuario"
        android:id="@+id/etEmailL"
        android:layout_marginTop="116dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Contraseña"
        android:id="@+id/etPassL"
        android:layout_below="@+id/etEmailL"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Entrar"
        android:id="@+id/btLoginL"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:layout_below="@+id/etPassL"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
        android:textColor="#25ae90" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Aun no eres miembro? Registrate!"
        android:id="@+id/tvRegistrarGo"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btLoginL"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

The problem is when i run the app, the button does nothing, but if i change the button Onclick for

> tvRegistrarGo.setText("Prueba");

the button works! I'm working with:
[this sdk version and this build tools version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSEvD.png)

This is the logcat i get when i pressed one hundred times the button, but if i press once the edit text with the onclick it appears on the logcat:

```
01-26 23:21:51.309 6706-6706/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
01-26 23:21:51.476 6706-6742/com.example.neak.phore D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
01-26 23:21:51.482 6706-6706/com.example.neak.phore D/Atlas: Validating map...
01-26 23:21:51.528 6706-6742/com.example.neak.phore I/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.BF.1.1.1_RB1.05.01.00.042.030_msm8974_LA.BF.1.1.1_RB1__release_AU ()
                                                                  OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.25.03.06
                                                                  Build Date: 05/17/15 Sun
                                                                  Local Branch: mybranch10089422
                                                                  Remote Branch: quic/LA.BF.1.1.1_rb1.22
                                                                  Local Patches: NONE
                                                                  Reconstruct Branch: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.BF.1.1.1_RB1.05.01.00.042.030 + 6151be1 +  NOTHING
01-26 23:21:51.529 6706-6742/com.example.neak.phore I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
01-26 23:21:51.555 6706-6742/com.example.neak.phore D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
01-26 23:21:51.627 6706-6706/com.example.neak.phore I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@1dfc7494 time:17054805
01-26 23:22:48.574 6706-6706/com.example.neak.phore I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.example.neak.phore time:17111752
01-26 23:22:48.715 6706-6706/com.example.neak.phore I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@815ccf4 time:17111893
01-26 23:22:52.005 6706-6706/com.example.neak.phore I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@1dfc7494 time:17115184
```

Comment: Are there any errors in your logcat?

Comment: What error are you getting? Please provide logcat logs.

Comment: It doesn´t appear nothing when i click the button, but if i change the Onclick for log.e("try","try"); looks like it works. If i swap it back doesn´t work :( The logcat doesnt get any click on the button

Comment: You have two buttons. which button has a problem.

Comment: The one which is a button, the other one is an edittext that you can click to go to another activity.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are reading the values of your `EditText`s *before* the user has a chance to enter them.

Change this:

```
    final String email = etEmail.getText().toString();
    final String pass = etPassL.getText().toString();

    btLoginL.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            EnviarDatos(email, pass);
        }
```

to this

```
    btLoginL.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            EnviarDatos(
                etEmail.getText().toString(),
                etPassL.getText().toString() );
        }
```

Comment: @IsmaelGarcia The above answer fixes one of the problems in your code. Now explain what you mean when you say doesn't work. Debug your code and see what is happening in your `EnviarDatos` function.

Comment: I edited the post, now you can see the logcat. The problem is that it doesnt appear to be a botton :( Anyway thank's for your time! :D